# Twitter Entities not found

Tags: twitter, tweepy

I have been using Tweepy (python lib for Twitter API).

Lately I have been getting this error for some tweets on twitter search and I have set include_entities = True.

```
AttributeError: 'SearchResult' object has no attribute 'entities'
```

Because of this error, I am unable to get access to the media_url(images) shared on those tweets. Would like to know if the prob is with the library(tweepy) / Twitter API or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Could you add your code to your question, please?